# grid matrix wont tally correctly

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, grid, cs50

I'm working on CS50s Tideman project however I'm doing all the coding in Python instead of C. I'm on the part where I need to generate a grid to keep track of the votes the candidates are getting and for some reason whenever I try to generate a grid that's variably based on the number of candidates, the point tallying stops working. If I use a fixed number of candidates and a pre-sized grid the tallying works though.
For example the pre-sized grid for four candidates looks like this

```
candidates = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Tom', 'Mike']

grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Now when I generate a variably sized grid also based on 4 candidates it comes out the same

```
candidates = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Tom', 'Mike']
grid = []
rows = []

for i in candidates:
    rows.append(0)

for j in candidates:
    grid.append(rows)

grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I've even compared the lists to see if the program recognizes they are the same and they come out as equal.

```
candidates = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Tom', 'Mike']
grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

grid2 = []
rows = []
for i in candidates:
    rows.append(0)

for j in candidates:
    grid2.append(rows)

if grid == grid2:
    print('Equal')
else:
    print('Not')

Equal
```

Now even though the lists are the same when I run the program to tally the votes it counts them differently.

```
votes = [['Mike', 'Joe', 'Bob', 'Tom']]

count = 0
count2 = 0
for vote in votes:
    while count < len(vote) - 1:
        for i in range(vote.index(vote[-1]) - vote.index(vote[count])):
            grid[candidates.index(vote[count])][(candidates.index(vote[count2 + 1]))] += 1
            count2 += 1
        count += 1
        count2 = count
        continue
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    continue
```

I run that same program for each version of the grid which are supposed to be equal but the output at the end is different. If I print the resulting grid from when I pre-size it to 4x4 the output is

```
for _ in grid:
    print(_)

[0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
```

But when I print the grid using the variably sized generated one I get

```
[2, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 3, 0]
```

I need the output of the variably sized grid that's based on the number of candidates to be the same as if I pre-sized the grid.

Comment: I'd recommend using numpy arrays for creating the grids - they are more suited for those kind of problems and then the code should also be easier to debug

Comment: genius, watched a quick tutorial and fixed in two secs

Comment: Have you figured out what the problem was?

Comment: I did not figure out the original problem and why it wasn’t tallying right. but classifying it as a numpy array immediately caused it to tally correctly.